# Location of the temp folder on remote windows

Tags: windows, networking, vbscript, wmi

How can I determine location of the temp folder on remote Windows machine?

I am able to connect to it using

```
objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, _
                              "root\cimv2", _
                              strUser, _
                              strPass)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bearing in mind every local or domain user can have their own path, you can query the `Win32_Environment` class:

```
Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objSWbemLocator = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, _
    "root\CIMV2", _
    strUser, _
    strPass)

Set colItems =objSWbemLocator.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Environment WHERE Name='TEMP' AND SystemVariable=FALSE AND username='machine_or_domain_name\\user_whos_temp_path_you_require'", "WQL", 48)

For Each objItem In colItems
    msgbox  objItem.VariableValue
Next
```

Comment: Alex, any ideas why the same method wouldn't get me %USERPROFILE% variable? I just changed `Name='TEMP'` to `Name='USERPROFILE'`.

Using your code i was able to get "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp".

Comment: Yes its not expanded, nor does it appear to be available via Win32_Environment, what do you want to do with it? "%USERPROFILE%" is valid on the target machine

Comment: Maybe I need absolute path. Not sure yet. Just interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure but have you tried using the "%TEMP%" variable as the remote folder string? I think windows automatically expands it to the configured temporary folder on the machine.

Comment: I think it will be interpreted locally. And I need an absolute path. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No. Since it is a server connect, the folder string may be interpreted remotely as well. Besides, once you are connected to the folder, you can get the present working directory right?

Comment: What do you mean by "you are connected to the folder"?